# Firebase onauth not fired for the second tab

Tags: authentication, firebase

In my single-page-application I call firebase.unauth() when user clicks the 'logout' button. This causes firebase client to unauth (no surprise here) and I got firebase.onAuth(callback) called (with null argument, as it should be).

So far so good.

The problem occurs, when I open the second tab (i.e. I'm authenticated in two  tabs simultaneously). In such a case, clicking logout in tab A does not lead to the onAuth callback in tab B; this tab is completely unaware that its firebase client is not authenticated any more (until I F5 the page and I make the firebase client to realize the horrible truth).

I'm not sure if I should look at it as a feature or bug; however, it's hard to imagine a case, when such behavior would be beneficial.

I could build some workaround to make my app work properly, but all solutions I can think of are between this-is-not-very-robust-ish and omg-such-basic-functionality-should-be-in-the-core-of-the-system-ish.

Is this a bug I should report? If not, is there some proper way how to get the (obviously needed) behavior (i.e. all tabs are notified about the fact, that user is no longer there)

Comment: I just found out, that it's even worse: when I unauthenticate in one tab, the second tab is half-authenticated: it can perform requests (even validation rules requiring sign-in user are OK with this). However, when I refresh the second tab, the authentication is lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote to Firebase support; they explained to me the technical details that lead to this situation. However the half-authenticated-half-not state is viewed as a desirable (at least, for now).

There should be something done about Firebase auth in general - so, stay tuned :)

Comment: how is the half-authenticated-half-not state desirable?